# Is AnimationDrawable.start() run in new thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I read the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

It extends DrawableContainer which seen like a kind of UI, and it implements Runnable, so it should run in a new thread (It should right? since it implements Runnable). Then in this case, should we follow the rule "only update UI component in UI thread"?

I have tested a program that perform a heavy loop after AnimationDrawable.start(), and program crashs (with famous stop responding error). Now I am totally confused, is AnimationDrawable.start() run in new thread?

Edit:

```
AnimationDrawable.start();

for (int i = 0 ; i< 10000000 ; i ++){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Note that a `Runnable` has nothing to do with threads. You can actually run a `Runnable` in a separate thread using the `Thread` class for instance. But you can also run it in current thread.

Comment: Sure but then it's a bit strange to use a Runnable...

Comment: @fiddler Yes, usually for our own class that implement Runnable, has nothing to do with thread, but normally the framework class that implement Runnable should be related to thread right? Ok, it may not be necessary, but then we wonder why they implement this with Runnable?

Comment: Sure. But `Runnable` is also useful to execute code which depends on API level (to avoid `VerifyError`) or to provide a callback (similar to a listener) to a method.

Comment: @fiddler Ya, you are right, I just realize android post it back UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know why it implements Runnable :

```
new Thread(){
   public void run(){
     AnimationDrawable.start();
   }
}.start();

for (int i = 0 ; i< 10000000 ; i ++){
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

I thought after I dispatch the `start()` to new thread, it will run in a new thread and not causing any "no responding error", but in fact it still crashes. Now I know it implements Runnable because Android posts it back to the UI thread to execute.

Comment: It can only be accepted by you. I guess. (but there is a delay to accept a self-anwser)

Comment: @fiddler Ha, it is just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

There is no new Thread started within this class. Actually, this component will create a new animation frame everytime it is drawn on screen. Nothing more.

I don't know what you mean exactly by "a program that perform a heavy loop after AnimationDrawable.start()", but it's clear to me that any operation performed by AnimationDrawable has to be fast, basically nothing more than an image swap must be performed here.

Comment: Hi, the link you posted is not source code. I have edited the original post. Do you know why it implements Runnable?

Comment: "but it's clear to me that any operation performed by AnimationDrawable has to be fast" now I know why you said this, because it execute in UI thread, so it must be fast.